# ROS website down?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm experiencing problems when going to the ROS website at [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org). I've tested this with three different internet providers and five different devices, all located in Belgium. They all fail to load the webpage, with this error code retrieved from Chromium:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

However, I am able to ping [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org). Is this issue being experienced anywhere else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60681/ros-website-down?/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-04-15**:
Same here, try letting people know in the ros-users list

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2013-04-15**:
Same problem from Paris, France ...

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-04-15**:
http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ros.org says "ros.org looks down from here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found this at the mailing list archive:

> We're working on restoring it.  We'll
> let you know when it's back online. In
> the mean time you can use one of
> several mirrors listed below.
>
> Tully
>
> - Asia:
>
>   - Tokyo, Japan "http://ros.jsk.imi.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/roswiki/"
>   - Tokyo, Japan (tarball) "http://mirrors.go-part.com/ros/"
>   - Tokyo, Japan (tarball - ftp) "ftp://mirrors.go-part.com/ros/"
>   - Tokyo, Japan (tarball - rsync) "http://www.ros.org/wiki/rsync%3A//mirrors.go-part.com/ros/"
> - Europe:
>
>   - Freiburg, Germany "http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/roswiki/"
>   - Lisbon, Portugal "http://ftp.isr.ist.utl.pt/pub/roswiki/"
>   - Barcelona, Catalonia "http://devel.iri.upc.edu/docs/roswiki/"
>   - Porto, Portugal "http://www.isep.ipp.pt/roswiki/"
> - North America:
>
>   - College Park, Maryland "http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/"
>   - Philadelphia, Pennsylvania "http://www.pennros.org/"
>     *([www.pennros.org](http://www.pennros.org)
>     )*
>   - Austin, Texas "http://www.cs.utexas.edu/ros/"

This works somewhat for me.

---

Originally posted by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) with karma: 386 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4